# file.mkdirs() make new dir but cannot read

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File("/ca.uwo.csd.cs2212.team05/src/main/resources/LifeLongData");
    dir.mkdirs();
    File file = new File("/ca.uwo.csd.cs2212.team05/src/main/resources/LifeLongData/check.dat");
    file.createNewFile();
    System.out.println(dir.canRead());
    System.out.println(dir.canWrite());
    System.out.println(dir.canExecute());
    System.out.println(new File("/ca.uwo.csd.cs2212.team05/src/main/resources/LifeLongData/check.dat").exists());
}
```

I am doing a java app, and try to check make some directory when it initalize,
however, when I do those, it give me all true but I cannot find them in my file explorer window. 
So where is the file?
I am using java 8, eclipse Mars, and Windows 10, all files are not hidden.

Comment: Have you looked in your workspace project folder?

Comment: How about using file.canRead() instead of dir.canRead()

Comment: Also you're not really going to want to put files into your arc directory like this, as the src directory won't exist once the app is packaged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply try

```
    System.out.println(file.getAbsoluteFile());
```

to check the absolute file path. Probably this will locate in

```
    C:\ca.uwo.csd.cs2212.team05\src\main\resources\LifeLongData\
```

To include this in your project directory use a period (.) like

```
    "./ca.uwo.csd.cs2212.team05/src/main/resources/LifeLongData"
```

Comment: well I see, how can i save it at relative source path under my project folder, thanks

Comment: @neo-zhang you can use ./yourpath, Remember in java period (.) means the working directory of the project.

Answer (score 0):

first : find the local of your project on windows filesystem

secode : open the class floder of your project

and then you will find this file ..